# How do you work with big array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, cluster-computing

I need to create a big array in python from Sqlite database. It's size is 1000_000_000*1000_000_000 and each item is one or zero. Actually, my computer can't store in RAM this volume of information. Maybe someone have idea how to work in this situation?  Maybe store these vectors in database or there is some framework for similar needs? If i am able to do this, then i need to build clusters, that problem frighten me not less, with this information size.
Thanks in advance/

Comment: Basically you need to change your approach - with data frame that big you'd better employ some other scheme rather "load everything in memory". What scheme in particular heavily depends on what are you trying to achieve. Notable examples: batch processing (load subset, process, unload, load next), search trees (for search, obviously), etc.

Comment: you may want to look at [Apache Spark SQL](http://spark.apache.org/sql/)

Comment: Probably you can store the array in file. `each item is one or zero` - so, you exactly know what item in what position of file.

Comment: I forgot to say one important thing. There are a lot of mostly empty vectors, that is some of the vectors contain only zeros. I think to try use parseMatrix  through numPy or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I also work with really big datasets (complete genomes or all possible gene combinations) and i store these in a zipped database with pickle. this way it is ram efficient and uses a lot less hard disk memory.
I suggest you try that.